# How to remove lines containing multiple matches?

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I found many answers for my other questions. But none for this one.
I want to remove lines containing let's say: AA and BB Not AA or BB.
Ex:

INPUT

```
AABBCCDDEE

CCBBDDEE

CCAADDEE

AACCBBEEDD
```

OUTPUT must be:

```
CCBBDDEE

CCAADDEE
```

Linux or Windows commands in grep, awk, sed, soon and if possible provide me on other programming languages also.

Comment: What have you tried so far? This is not the site where people will give you the answers without seeing that you even try to do it by yourself.

Answer (score 2):

By Grep:

```
grep -Ev 'AA.*BB|BB.*AA'  infile
```

By Awk :

```
awk '!(/AA/ && /BB/)' infile
```